# Links to complete Wordpress blog via read more tag, email, etc show raw code

Tags: wordpress

This Wordpress blog is glitchy. The biggest problem is that links to the full post via the read more tag, a link from Facebook, or the email newsletter sometimes show code instead of the formatted post.
This doesn't happen every time so is not easily replicable.
I have updated plugins, deleted unused plugins, and gotten a new theme.
What could be causing this and how can I prevent it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtvhy.jpg)

Hosted on Siteground, cleared cache, updated Wordpress, no change that I can tell.